# What part of speech is "quiet" in "And quiet flows the Don"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

The Mikhail Sholokov novel "Тихий Дон" (Quiet Don) is translated "And quiet flows the Don". In this title, is the word "quiet" an adjective or adverb?

If it's an adverb modifying the verb "flows", why doesn't it take the normal adverb form "quietly"?

Is it possible to say it is a predicate adjective, and "flows" is a copular verb? If so, are there other cases loke this?

Comment: A possibly related question on ELL SE: **[“waterway … flowed sombre” - Should Joseph Conrad have used an adverb, not an adjective?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46364/waterway-flowed-sombre-should-joseph-conrad-have-used-an-adverb-not-an)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would describe it as a adjective functioning as complement, rather than as predicate (I don't think you can really call "flows" copular, even if it has been inserted by the translator).

This is a rather poetic construction, which leads me to

> Green grow the rushes O!

But I haven't thought of any other examples.

Comment: "Do not go gentle into that good night" (Dylan Thomas).

Comment: "Where the Sun Set Crimson and the Moon Rose Red" https://muse.jhu.edu/article/424286/pdf

Comment: "[And the sky went wan, and the wind came cold, and the sun rose dripping, a bucketful of gold](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poetrymagazine/poems/detail/14404)" (Edna St. Vincent Millay, "Recuerdo")

Comment: Why have you described it as a complement instead of an adjunct/modifier? It looks like a depictive adjunct to me ... Some people might describe it as a secondary predicate, but I can't see how it can be a complement? (scratches head)

Comment: @Araucaria,  I described it as that because the structure seems to me to be similar to what it would be if the verb were a copula; but I have no particlar theoretical justification in mind. If it is an adjunct, what is it adjoined to?

Comment: @ColinFine So the second bit of a copula is a complement because the verb in question sets up a special slot for that phrase. In contrast an 'adjunct' or 'modifier' or 'adverbial' is an extra bit that we can tag on to a clause or a phrase. I don't know why they chose the term adjunct apart from that it's a phrase that's just 'stuck next to' something. So in "She is in the park" the phrase "in the park" is a complement of the verb *BE* - because such copula verbs set up a space for a complement describing the subject. But in "She plays football in the park" the PP *in the park* is an adjunct ..

Comment: @ColinFine ... because the verb *play* doesn't set up a special place for a location. It does set up a space for what's being played though. So *football* is a complement there (direct objects are a special type of complement). Erm, I'm trying to make sense but don't know if I am?

Comment: @Araucaria: I meant, what is it an adjunct to: I wasn't trying to be cute about the etymology of 'adjunct'. But as I say, I'm not attached to the idea of its being a complement; that's just the structure that occurred to me. It's not common to have an adjective as an adjunct, as far as I can think; but then this is not a common construction.

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, you're making sense, and I'm happy to defer to your suggestion.

Comment: @ColinFine Ah, so in the sentence "You can eat garlic raw" the adjective *raw* is an adjunct (it doesn't fill a special slot set up be *EAT*). So is *naked* in *You can eat pizza naked*. You're right that adjectives that don't modify nouns are most often complements (it seems to me). But this one isn't - I don't think - in this case.

Comment: @ColinFine Sorry for the cross-commenting.